# Pre-Generated Entity Framework Views in Azure?

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I am looking to use pre-generated EF views per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx to speed load time.  This works fine in my local environment and I have connection strings that include something along the lines of "metadata=~/bin/Models\DSManagedCoModel.csdl|~/bin/Models\DSManagedCoModel.ssdl|~/bin/Models\DSManagedCoModel.msl".  When I debug using localhost, it worked great.  Then when I try it using 127.0.0.1 it was giving me an error "The specified metadata path is not valid".  I fixed this for 127.0.0.1 by adding a build event that copies the files to the Azure cloud project bin directory (actually, its Models subfolder).  When I try to publish to Azure, though, I get a similar message "The specified metadata path is not valid".
Is it possible to use pre-generated EF views with Azure?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest embedding the CSDL, etc., as resources instead of keeping them as files. Add the CSDL, etc., files to your project and specify "Embedded Resoruce" as the build action. Then you can do:

```
metadata="res://MyAssembly.dll/MyAssembly.bin.Models.DSManagedCoModel.csdl|  //etc.
```

[Use Reflector to discover the true resource name. I wrote an article on connect strings which should help](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/).

Note that these files aren't actually the pregenerated views; they're just the model. But you need them to generate the views with EDMGen.

Comment: Craig, it's an honor to have you reply.  Your blog and answers here on SO are a tremendous resource...  This got me closer... the first time it said something about not finding the resource.  Then when I tried the res://*/ trick it finds it but says "The EntityContainer name must be unique".  It is unique across edmx files (I have several), but I note that my edmx contains a section marked <!-- CSDL content --> which repeats the info from above.  Seems like a clue...

Comment: If you're using separate CSDL/MSL/SSDL files, then the EDMX is no longer used at all (except as the source for the above) and shouldn't be referenced at runtime.

Comment: Looking more closely, the contents of the CSDL (and the other files) are clearly embedded in the EDMX.  In fact, they appear to be identical.  I'm assuming one or the other should be removed?  FYI, I have EntityDeploy as my EDMX build action and Embedded Resource (do not copy) for the csdl & related files.

Comment: Huh...  Well a search of my solution finds <EntityContainer Name="DSAdminViewEntities" in only two places -- once in the edmx and once in the csdl.

Comment: Right, you probably have references to both. EDMX build action is correct (EntityDeploy). ER(dnc) is correct for CSDL, etc. EDMX should not be used at runtime in this case.

Comment: So I still have the same "EntityContainer name must be unique" error even though it only appears once in the solution...  any other ideas on that?

Comment: Interesting.  I checked and didn't see any duplicate files.  I was inspired to do a little cleanup though.  Maybe too much.  Now I get an error from my pre-build event: error MyWebRole\bin\Models\DSViewModel.ssdl' given for the argument 'inssdl' is not a valid file or directory.  This is a cloud project, so I wonder whether my build events are correct?  This thread here has me wondering it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/a75f316a-2e36-4689-bc96-09efd8bd016f

Comment: Well, that's a physical path. You can look for that file.

Comment: OK, I'm back now where I was (drops of sweat hitting keyboard...). If I use: connectionString="metadata=res://MyProjectWebRole.dll/Models.DSUserModel.csdl|res://MyProjectWebRole.dll/Models.DSUserModel.ssdl|res://MyProjectWebRole.dll/Models.DSUserModel.msl;provider=......  then I get System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to resolve assembly 'MyProjectWebRole.dll'.  To clarify, I have a solution called MyProject, and a cloud project called MyProject and the main project, MyProjectWebRole.  I used Reflector on MyProjectWebRole\bin\MyProjectWebRole.dll and it showed 'Models.DSUserModel.csdl etc.

Comment: OK, thanks for all your help.  Getting closer.  When I get to the bottom of this, I'll let you know..

Comment: Craig, turns out you did help solve my original problem.  Once the issue here got fixed, I hit a new one that I thought was related.  In fact, all my entities work fine except the login related ones b/c of some issues with MembershipProvider using Azure.  So problem solved here, and working on that now.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Yup, the EF connection strings were fixed with your help.  My MembershipProvider connection string needed work.  All set now, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this excellent post which really helped sort through some of the confusion with pre-generated views:
http://blog.willbeattie.net/2010/04/pre-generating-views-in-entity.html